# Install private key from CSR file in Keychain on Mac?

Tags: macos, keychain

I accidentally deleted my private key from keychain i have that same CSR file and iPhone Distribution certificate, i want to install private key from CSR file. when i install iPhone Distribution certificate i am not getting private key in keychain access. i don't have developer account access now.  how to do that?

[image]

Comment: i think you need to create new CSR for it.

Comment: @NitinGohel. How to get private key for iPhone Distribution certificate as shown for selected certificate?.

Comment: check https://www.codementor.io/ios/tutorial/apple-developer-distribution-certificate

Comment: @NitinGohel. i checked that. i have iPhone Distribution certificate. but when i install it in keychain i can get private key in their.

Comment: you need to create wall process again from keychain you need to create CSR and create cer using this CSR and download then install then you get private key and all work like charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate signing request (CSR) does not include the private key, only the public key. If you don't have some sort of backup (of the keychain or an exported private key), you will not be able to recreate it.

Comment: i have iPhone Distribution certificate. but when i install it i can't see private key in it.  iPhone Distribution certificate contain private key? i can't see it in keychain as in image shown. but can see my other's account

Comment: The certificate itself does not contain the private key, although people are sometimes sloppy, and refer to the certificate+private key together as "the certificate". If you see the private key in some other account, try exporting it from there, and then importing it to the keychain where you want it.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681696

I google private key in CSR, and find *HERE* and above post.